# json as string, not sure if what ive done so far is also correct

Tags: c#, string

Hi I need this json result to be sent as a string

```
 {"tickerIds":[913256135],"type":"102"}
```

I have this so far

```
"{\"tickerIds\":\"[913354090]\",\"type\":\"102\"}"
```

the problem is that [913354090] doesn't need to be encased in " ". Im not even sure if what I have done will be correct.

Wasnt quite sure of what tags to use for this

Comment: how are you genereting the json string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you create your Json result so I can't help you with the best solution for the "[]" but you can do this to get the expected result :

```
        // your initial json
        string yourInitialJson= "{\"tickerIds\":\"[913354090]\",\"type\":\"102\"}";

        // remove [] from for your [913354090]
        yourInitialJson = yourInitialJson.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");

        // escape characters with Regex method
        string unescapeCharacters = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(yourInitialJson);

        Console.WriteLine(unescapeCharacters);
        // Result : {"tickerIds":"913354090","type":"102"}
```